# FileStream creates an empty file when an error is thrown in CopyToAsync

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to implement a file upload component in my Blazor web application. I am using the approach provided on the Core Blazor `InputFile` component documentation page.

Here is my code:

```
await using FileStream fs = new(path, FileMode.Create);
await file.OpenReadStream(MaxFileSize).CopyToAsync(fs);
```

If `OpenReadStream` throws an error, (`MaxFileSize` is exceeded, etc.) the file should not be uploaded. However, since I already created the file stream, an empty file is created at the provided path (an empty text document for example). I am a C# and Blazor newbie so I'm probably just overlooking an easy solution. How can I ensure that an empty file is not uploaded even if an error is thrown?

Comment: You could always wrap it in a try/catch block and try removing the file again if an exception is thrown. I don't think that there is an atomic way of creating-and-writing-and-closing the file.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can create the file *after* you've called `OpenReadStream`:

```cs
using var input = file.OpenReadStream(MaxFileSize);
await using FileStream output = new(path, FileMode.Create);
await input.CopyToAsync (output);
```

That could still fail leaving an empty or incomplete file of course, because `CopyTo` could fail, but it at least avoids the problem when `OpenReadStream` throws an exception.

Comment: I've suggested an edit but it might not be accepted (because it was only 5 chars and edits needed to be 6) so just in case, for others using this answer, you might find you need the `CopyToAsync` method rather than just `CopyTo` on the last line - particularly if working in an async environment like Blazor. Using this code earlier today worked when using `CopyToAsync` instead :-)

Comment: @FraserG: Doh, thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it will be enough to add a file delete action in the catch block.

So your example would look like following:

```
try 
{ 
    await using FileStream fs = new(path, FileMode.Create);
    await file.OpenReadStream(MaxFileSize).CopyToAsync(fs);
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
    File.Delete(path); 
    //Re-throw exception 
    throw; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's actually throwing an error. Break up the statements and surround with a try catch?

```
try
{
     var strm = await file.OpenReadStream(MaxFileSize);
     strm.CopyToAsync(fs);
}
catch
{

}
```

Or check the stream for content before copying in an if statement.